# Laptop keeps restarting after start installation windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, iso-image, windows-installation

Yesterday I bought 8 GB RAM and SSD (Samsung 840 PRO) for my **eMachines E732G**. I installed RAM instead of my old RAM. Also I installed SSD instead of HDD, and I installed HDD instead of DVD-RW with help HDD Caddy. Laptop worked well. I could launch Windows 7 x86, which was installed on a HDD. Also I could use my SSD, since I made initialization it.

Today I want to install a Windows 7 x64 on my SSD and format old HDD. I create **Acronis Disk Director 11 USB Bootable**. Then I booted with Acronis Disk Director 11 and I formatted my system old disk with Windows 7 x86.

After that, I made a **windows 7 x64 bootable usb** with help **UltraISO**. I set first priority of booting for USB in BIOS. Unfortunately, process of installing Windows 7 x64 is failing.

When I turn on my Laptop, I see, as Windows unzip some files for installing. Then I see a screensaver of Windows within a few seconds. Then there is a reboot, and these steps are repeating.

Note! I have tried install Windows 7 x64, Windows 8 x64, Windows 8 x86 and Ubuntu 12.04. Always, I see this error. At the beginning, process of installing OS is starting, and then reboot is happening.

I have made a video, which shows my problem. Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k2qxdxujmonh5mb/error.mp4.

---

**Upd.**

The problem is incompatible RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things to take into consideration:

**Bootable device is corrupted**

Consider trying other software to create bootable Windows drive. As an example:
http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool

It's simple and fast tool made by Microsoft that never let me down.

**Corrupted boot sector of your SSD**

Try connecting your SSD through SATA-USB adapter or as a second drive (as you do have now) then try to reformat it. After that, try repeating the installation process.

**SSD is working in wrong mode**

Some newer SSD happen to work properly only in AHCI mode. Please check in your BIOS wheter it's using AHCI or IDE mode.

**[Most probable] Boot sector is created on your HDD instead of SSD**
Just remove HDD while installing OS on your SSD. After finishing installation of either Ubuntu or Windows, you can mount HDD through your HDD caddy again.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Today I tried different options. I tried to remove the SSD, HDD. Also, I tried to change their positions (SSD to Hdd-Caddy, Hdd to Sata). Unfortunately, the problem still persists.

Comment: Consider checking other options I've provided.
You can't install any OS on either SSD nor HDD?

Comment: I have AHCI SATA Mode. You are right, I can't install Windows 7 x64, Windows 8 x64, Windows 8 x86 and Ubuntu 12.04 on my SSD and HDD. The problem is same.

Comment: Ok, let's keep excluding things. You mentioned RAM swap. Have you tried to use old RAMs? Also for every test for now please only have one disk connected directly to laptop (not by DVD caddy).

Comment: today, I have not tried to use old RAMs. Thank you for the idea. Tomorrow, I will change RAMs. I will write the result.

Comment: thank you. I put the old memory, and the problem was solved.