# Incompatible RAM with a laptop

Tags: laptop, memory, hardware-failure, compatibility

Recently, I bought a [RAM (Vengeance CMSX8GX3M2A1600C9](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/vengeance-8gb-high-performance-sodimm-memory-upgrade-kit-cmsx8gx3m2a1600c9)) for my laptop (eMachines E732G). Yesterday I installed the RAM on my laptop.

There was a [problem](https://superuser.com/questions/791532/laptop-keeps-restarting-after-start-installation-windows-7/791584#791584). I could not install any operating system (Windows, Ubuntu). Also I could not load already installed an operating system. I saw the screensaver of the operating system and then reboot occurred. You can see it on [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k2qxdxujmonh5mb/error.mp4).

My question is, why this RAM is not compatible with the laptop? Can I do something to make this memory work? Or should I buy another RAM.

Comment: Poke around in the BIOS do you see settings for memory timings like RAS/CAS?  If your BIOS allows you to you may be able to adjusting the memory timings to work.

Comment: The link you provided says  9-9-9-24 is correct for 1333 or 1666mhz if the memory is running faster 1866 or higher you will either have to force it to 1666mhz or try increasing the timings.

Comment: @cybernard, My BIOS is very poor. I can only change the time, boot priorities and a few settings. What I can do in this case?

Comment: @cybernard, also my BIOS shows, that RAM == 8 GB.

Comment: @cybernard, It is interesting, when I had Windows 7 x86, everything worked, but the system could see 3 GB of RAM. And when I put Windows 7 x64, the error appears.

Comment: Does the laptop now have 2 sticks of RAM? Swap them around.  I found an unlocked version of your BIOS, but sadly no usefull memory timings were present.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16175/discussion-between-denis-and-cybernard).

Comment: @cybernard, At present, my laptop have 2 sticks of old RAM (1 + 2 GB). In the morning I tried to swap sticks.